# Compare an xml element with a variable php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to compare an element in XML with a variable using simpleXML, but I can't get it right. This is what i have so far:

**PHP**

> $xml = simplexml_load_file('0.xml');

```
    if((string)$xml->stickers->sticker->id == $id) {  //<-- THIS LINE
        //code to be executed
    }
```

**XML**

```
<stickers>
    <sticker>
        <id>1</id>
        <content>StickerContent</content>
    </sticker>
</stickers>
```

This leaves me with the **Notice:***Trying to get property of non-object* on the line i marked and i don't know how to fix it.

**var_dump($xml)**

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) {
  ["sticker"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (5) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["content"]=>
      string(1) "p"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
if ((string) $xml->sticker->id == $id)
```

Though if you have multiple sticker elements it would be:

```
if ((string) $xml->sticker[0]->id == $id)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it, but i still get the same error.

Comment: Is `$xml = simplexml_load_file('0.xml');` even getting any results? Update your post with the contents using `var_dump($xml);`.

Comment: @alex since `stickers` is the root node wouldnt it be `$xml->sticker[0]->id`

Comment: Yeah just testing and thats the case.

Comment: That works. Thank you! Sorry i didn't clarify that i had multiple sticker elements.